# Multiple conditions in selecting pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two similar dataframes. df1 and df2 with same structure. And they have same data in one column(policyID) and other columns may have different data and one column contains timestamp based on that I need to segregate them.
df1 -

```
policyID,statecode,county,timestamp
114455,FL,CLAY COUNTY,2015-12-23
```

df2-

```
policyID,statecode,county,timestamp
114455,FL,CLAY COUNTY,2016-12-34
```

I need to create a new dataframe say df3 which contains data from df1 if timestamp of df1 is higher and from df2 if timestamp of df2 is higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), last need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) or [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
print (df1)
            0    1             2           3
0  114453   FL   CLAY COUNTY  2016-12-23
1  114455  FL1  CLAY COUNTY1  2016-12-11
2  114457  FL1  CLAY COUNTY1  2016-12-11

print (df2)
        0    1             2           3
0  114453  FL1  CLAY COUNTY1  2016-12-15
1  114455  FL1  CLAY COUNTY1  2016-12-15
2  114457  FL1  CLAY COUNTY1  2016-12-15

df1.iloc[:,3] = pd.to_datetime(df1.iloc[:,3])
df2.iloc[:,3] = pd.to_datetime(df2.iloc[:,3])

df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df3 = df3.sort_values(df3.columns[3]).groupby(df3.columns[0]).first()
print (df3)
          1             2          3
0                                   
114453  FL1  CLAY COUNTY1 2016-12-15
114455  FL1  CLAY COUNTY1 2016-12-11
114457  FL1  CLAY COUNTY1 2016-12-11
```

---

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df4 = df3.sort_values(df3.columns[3]).groupby(df3.columns[0]).last()
print (df4)
          1             2          3
0                                   
114453   FL   CLAY COUNTY 2016-12-23
114455  FL1  CLAY COUNTY1 2016-12-15
114457  FL1  CLAY COUNTY1 2016-12-15
```

Comment: I have doubt ,drop_duplicate will remove duplicates ,how it will compare timestamp?
without keep argument it will save first record irrespective of timestamp

Comment: ops, sorrry, give me asec

Comment: Please check edit - added sort_values for sorting dataframe by `timestamp`

Comment: In my case,i read dataframe from csv with argument header=None
so my dataframe is like 
df1 = 0    114455        FL  CLAY COUNTY 2015-12-23
df2 = 0    114455       FL1  CLAY COUNTY1 2016-12-15

hence while running 
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1).sort_values(['18']).drop_duplicates(['crc])
i am getting cannot sort values on duplicate columns

Comment: So  think you  can add parameter `names=['policyID','statecode','county','timestamp']`

Comment: ...to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)  think

Comment: I have many columns ,total 36 columns in one csv ,hence adding header is not good idea.
is there any other way?

Comment: Yes, then you can use `df1.iloc[:,3] = pd.to_datetime(df1.iloc[:,3])`, 
`df2.iloc[:,3] = pd.to_datetime(df2.iloc[:,3])` and

`df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_values([3]).drop_duplicates([0])`. Numbers are names of columns.

Comment: And if upgrade `pandas` to last version (`0.19.1`), there are not duplicates columns.